# Restsharp runs slow

Tags: restsharp

I have a restful webservice and in a .net client I use RestSharp to call the rest API. The problem is using RestSharp, it takes about 100ms but only take ~ 30ms if I use SoapUI.

Is there any advanced setting for making RestSharp run faster?

Answer (score 0):

RestSharp try to some auto configurations on proxy server each inital request, probably because of that SoapUI is faster. Maybe you can try this;

```
System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
```